# Merge tables into One WITH same generated number in both new tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I found some options to run a mysql query to migrate/split one table into 2 new tables, but one of the fields I would like to create on the new table has to be the same as in the other new table:

So from the "From_payments" table, I would like to create 2 new tables called: "To_paymenttransaction" and "To_paymentinfo". A lof of the field are predefined and some are from the old table. The only problem is that the predefined field "paymentinfoid" has to be the same is both new tables.

```
**To_paymenttransaction** --- < --- **From_payments**

paymenttransactionid ------- < --- (Generate next available number in this column)

paymentinfoid -------------- < --- (Generate next available number in this column)

transactionid --------------- < --- txn_id

state ---------------------- < --- (Set all to "1")

amount -------------------- < --- mc_gross

currency ------------------- < --- mc_currency

dateline -------------------- < --- payment_date

paymentapiid --------------- < --- (Set all to "1")

request -------------------- < --- (Set all to "NULL")

reversed ------------------- < --- (Set all to "0")

**To_paymentinfo** -----------< 

paymentinfoid -------------- < --- (Same generated number that goes to the paymentinfoif field in To_paymenttransaction table )

hash ----------------------- < --- (Set all to "Imported")

subscriptionid --------------- < --- (Set all to "1")

subscriptionsubid ------------ < --- ("2" IF above field mc_gross is 4, "1" IF above field mc_gross is 6, "0" IF above field mc_gross is 10)

userid   ---------------------- < --- userid

completed ------------------ < --- (Set all to "0")
```

Any ideas?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe generate the paymentinfoid on the original table before you split it.  Then you can copy that single entry into each of the new tables.

Comment: That sounds like a really good solution, however, the 2 tables where this info is going to be migrated to already has some data with paymentinfoid field. If this is the best/simplest method then I guess I can just just do as you suggested but have the original table start generating number from last available number in the new table.

How would I create a query to generate that number counting up and starting from X number?